# Windows 7 firewall with profiles

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

I'm going travelling soon and will be taking my laptop, I want to be able to lockdown bandwidth usage when I'm on a mobile connection.

What I need is a firewall that I can quickly toggle between different profiles so when I'm on mobile I can set the browser to be the only software that can access the internet but when on Wi-Fi I can allow all software.

Is there a 3rd party firewall or something that can configure the Windows Firewall easily?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I'm asking for software recommendation OR an easy to apply profiles to the BUILT-IN Windows firewall. Seems like something a "superuser" would need.

Comment: So remove the software rec part of the question. Then it will be on-topic.

Comment: Windows firewall already has built in profiles for different connections and connection types - use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I found was to install a 3rd party firewall (I chose Glasswire) which I can configure for travel and then turn on/off as needed.

[image]